# vb net break out from inner loop then move to outer loop

Tags: vb.net

hi guys i have a similar question from another thread in this site, so i take an example from there and added my problem in..

here it is

```
For Each t as trans in transaction
  For each h as item2 in items2
    For Each I As Item In Items
       If I = h Then 
       'i wanna break the for then move to next item2(h) and increment the i
       else
       'i wanna break the for then move to next trans(t) and reset the i starts from 1
       end if

    Next
  Next
next
```

i've already try this, but it's not working (GoTo, boolean)

```
For Each t as trans in transaction
    For each h as item2 in items2
      For Each I As Item In Items
         If I = h Then 
         i+=1
         GoTo flag1
         else
         i=1
         GoTo flag2
         end if
      Next
flag1:
    Next
flag2:
next
```

please help me solve this problem, thanks before
call @Neolisk @har07

Comment: Did `Exit For` not work?

Comment: it's worked but i need to `break` then `continue` the **outer for**

Comment: The inner loop never loops.  Bad code, easily replaced with an If() statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start:    For Each t as trans in transaction
            For each h as item2 in items2
             For Each I As Item In Items
               If I = h Then 
                 i+=1;
                 exit for
               else
                  Goto Start
               end if
            Next
          Next
        next
```

`Exit For` will break the inner for loop and in else part you can use `Label` method to brings the execution from the beginning as you said.. but this may leads to `overflow exception`

Comment: i've got an error connecting: timeout expired, max pool size was reached

Answer (score 0):

You use a boolean flag to control it:

```
Dim flag As Boolean = False
For Each t As Trans In Transaction
    For Each h As Item2 In Items2
        For Each i As Item In Items
            flag = false
            If i = h Then 
                Exit For
            Else
                flag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If flag Then Exit For
    Next
Next
```